# If we put a led light into a oscillating current, will it blink?

Tags: basic, logic-gates

Sorry for the misleading title cause I have no electronic knowledge.
It is a simple question.

[image: Current description]

This is the circuit diagram.
In case you don't see clearly, it is XOR GATE.
My question is what will happen with the LED light, will it turn on/off or blink ?

Comment: What speed do you estimate the exclusive or will oscillate at?

Comment: Without a current-limiting resistor the LED might be damaged.

Comment: look into the propagation delay of the IC in question. This will oscillate but at twice this time period (assuming equal hi->lo, lo->hi prop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the massless, frictionless, noiseless Perfect World (beware of the spherical cows) where DC is pure and logic signals only have two states, you will have made a high speed oscillator. The LED will blink, with a 50% duty cycle, at half the switching frequency of the gate. Since perfect gates run at ∞Hz it will be rather difficult to measure the pulse rate.

In a less perfect world, the gate will probably be unable to switch fast enough and will settle down into a noisy state, the final output probably varying between components. They aren't designed to be wired like that. Add a buffer and a simple RC delay.

In reality, the circuit you drew will burn out almost immediately. You've drawn a short circuit from the gate to ground via the LED. Hard to say which component will release the Magic Smoke first, but one of the two is going to have a short service life.

Answer (score 4):

It's a shame that we don't better encourage these learning questions on the stack, because this is a good one.

What you have stumbled across is an indeterminate state. While it is possible that the circuit may oscillate it would happen at an incredibly high speed. Whether or not the LED appears to be on would depend on how much time it spends forward biased each cycle, and the characteristic of the diode. I'm guessing it probably wouldn't be visible, but this depends on so many part specific factors it really is just a guess.

The problem is that combinational logic circuitry is purpose built to respond to input as fast as possible, and you've shorted the output to the input. This problem is the whole reason sequential, clocked logic exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer the intended question, and not analyze the circuit.

If you connect an LED to an oscillating (or pulsing) circuit, it will blink as fast as the oscillations.  These may be too fast to see, but they can be picked up on a photodetector and translated back to an electrical signal.  It is possible to transmit data this way.

You circuit as shown may not work as intended, but that's another matter (and should be a separate question).

Answer (score 0):

A CMOS xor gate with low enough operating voltage can oscillate, the LED can get a square wave voltage and nothing puffs the smoke out. I think this is possible if your LED has high enough forward voltage.

Let's assume the system oscillates. It must happen at several MHz, so no blinking can be seen by eye. It can be detected with fast enough instruments - except if the LED use fluorescent wavelength conversion to make short wavelength (blue or UV) radiation usable for lights. LEDs of this type are common in lamps. Their light decays so slowly that the light is virtually continuous if the voltage oscillates faster than at few hundred Hz.